# LambdaType vs FunctionType

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the difference? [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) show nothing on this, and their `help()` is identical. Is there an object for which `isinstance` will fail with one but not other?

Comment: They're the exact same type.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Then why's there two of them? Back-compatibility?

Comment: As far as I know, they've always been identical. I'm not aware of any good reason for both to exist, especially in Python 3.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to tell if a function object was a lambda or a def?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56451020/674039)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Back in 1994 I wasn't sure that we would always be using the same implementation type for lambda and def. That's all there is to it. It would be a pain to remove it, so we're just leaving it (it's only one line). If you want to add a note to the docs, feel free to submit a PR.

Comment: My [question](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/adc940eabfdb69c6adb3764f35fa00d057e3c3d5#diff-0f021aec4e35b86a3160d44069dec997R21) reached - IT'S HIM!

Answer (score 5):

See [`cpython/Lib/types.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a041e116db5f1e78222cbf2c22aae96457372680/Lib/types.py#L11-L13):

```
def _f(): pass
FunctionType = type(_f)
LambdaType = type(lambda: None)         # Same as FunctionType
```

Comment: Thanks; so why's there two of them? Back-compatibility to when one of them didn't exist?

Comment: Note that definition of `LambdaType` has not changed since the [earliest record](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/adc940eabfdb69c6adb3764f35fa00d057e3c3d5#diff-0f021aec4e35b86a3160d44069dec997R21) of it, from 1994. I'm not sure anyone but Guido could tell you why it was added.

Comment: @chepner Great, then maybe I'll ask him someday.

Comment: @chepner Also how did you track this down? Or did you just happen to know about it; if there a name for this method?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon `cpython/Lib` basically contains all the standard library modules that you can `import`. If you mean the specific commit, you can check [`git blame`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/a041e116db5f1e78222cbf2c22aae96457372680/Lib/types.py#L11-L13) (directly on GitHub, too!).

Comment: @chepner I DID IT!